# Code that gives an error that is not deleted when there is no element in the list on stack in C language

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list, function-definition

When I call the pop function with an empty list, it correctly outputs the "Stack is empty." message. However, after I add two elements to the list with two push function calls and then call the pop function twice without any problems, **the program crashes when I call the pop function for the third time with an empty list.** It freezes and does not return any output. Do you have any idea about it? I need your help. Thanks.

```
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.c". START
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.c". START 
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.c". START

#include <stdio.h> // THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.c" //
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack_ll.h" // Header file

int pop(node *root){
if(root == NULL){
    printf("Stack is empty.");
    return -1;
}

if(root->next == NULL){ // 1 eleman varsa
int rvalue = root->data;
    root = NULL;
    free(root);
    return rvalue;
}

node *iter = root;
while(iter->next->next != NULL){
    iter = iter->next;
}
node * temp = iter->next;
int rvalue = temp->data;
free(temp);
iter->next = NULL;

return rvalue;
}
node* push(node * root, int a){
if(root == NULL){
    root = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root -> data = a;
    root -> next = NULL;
    return root;
}
node * iter = root;
while(iter->next != NULL){
    iter = iter->next;
}
node * temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->data = a;
temp->next = NULL;
iter->next = temp;
return root; // push fonksiyonunu node ile tanımladık diye return etmeliyiz.
}

// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.c". END
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.c". END
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.c". END






// THIS FILE IS "test_stack_ll.c". START
// THIS FILE IS "test_stack_ll.c". START
// THIS FILE IS "test_stack_ll.c". START

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack_ll.h" // Header dosyası

int main(){
node * s = NULL;
s = push(s,15);
s = push(s,25);
s = push(s,35); 
printf("%d -> ", pop(s)); // IT WORKS
printf("%d -> ", pop(s)); // IT WORKS
printf("%d -> ", pop(s)); // IT DOESN'T WORK!
}

// THIS FILE IS "test_stack_ll.c". END
// THIS FILE IS "test_stack_ll.c". END
// THIS FILE IS "test_stack_ll.c". END



// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.h". START
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.h". START
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.h". START

#ifndef stack_ll
#define stack_ll    

typedef struct n{
int data;
struct n *next;
}node;

int pop(node*);
node* push(node *, int);

#endif

// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.h". END
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.h". END
// THIS FILE IS "stack_ll.h". END
```

Comment: You keep assigning the result of `push` to `s`. And you pass that to `pop`. So when will the argument to `pop` equal `NULL`?

Comment: The pop function should return NULL when there are no more elements in the stack it can operate on? @EmanuelP

Comment: _should_ maybe, but that's not what it does. It returns the value of the element popped. Besides, you discard the return value of `pop`. The argument you pass to `pop` is the last returned value from `push` - in all three calls. So never `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is invalid. For example the function `pop` deals with its local parameter `root` that contains a copy of the value of the passed original pointer. Changing the copy within the function does not change the original pointer

```
int pop(node *root){
if(root == NULL){
    printf("Stack is empty.");
    return -1;
}

if(root->next == NULL){ // 1 eleman varsa
int rvalue = root->data;
    root = NULL;
    free(root);
    return rvalue;
}
//...
```

In the above code snippet the statement

```
root = NULL;
```

does not change the original pointer `s` declared in main to `NULL`. It stays unchanged.

Also calling the function `free` after setting the pointer `root` to NULL

```
root = NULL;
free(root);
```

does not make sense.

You need to pass the pointer to the root node by reference through a pointer to it.

The function should be declared for example like

```
int pop( node **root, int *data );
```

It can be defined the following way

```
int pop( node **root, int *data )
{
    int success = *root != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        while ( ( *root )->next != NULL )
        {
            root = &( *root )->next;
        }

        *data = ( *root )->data;
        
        node *current = *root;

        *root = NULL;

        free( current );
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function is called like

```
int data;

pop( &s, &data );
printf("%d -> ", data );

pop( &s, &data );
printf("%d -> ", data );

pop( &s, &data );
printf("%d -> ", data );
```

Or like

```
int data;

if ( pop( &s, &data ) )
{
    printf("%d -> ", data );
}

if ( pop( &s, &data ) )
{
    printf("%d -> ", data );
}

if ( pop( &s, &data ) )
{
    printf("%d -> ", data );
}
```

Pay attention to that your organization of the stack is inefficient. You should add new nodes to the beginning of the list an remove them also from the beginning. Otherwise to add a new node or to remove a mode you have to traverse the whole list.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct n {
    int data;
    struct n *next;
}node;

int pop( node **root, int *data )
{
    int success = *root != NULL;

    if (success)
    {
        while (( *root )->next != NULL)
        {
            root = &( *root )->next;
        }

        *data = ( *root )->data;

        node *current = *root;

        *root = NULL;

        free( current );
    }

    return success;
}

node *push( node *root, int a ) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = ( node * )malloc( sizeof( node ) );
        root->data = a;
        root->next = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    node *iter = root;
    while (iter->next != NULL) {
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    node *temp = ( node * )malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    temp->data = a;
    temp->next = NULL;
    iter->next = temp;
    return root; // push fonksiyonunu node ile tanımladık diye return etmeliyiz.
}

int main( void )
{
    node *s = NULL;
    s = push( s, 15 );
    s = push( s, 25 );
    s = push( s, 35 );

    int data;

    if (pop( &s, &data ))
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", data );
    }

    if (pop( &s, &data ))
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", data );
    }

    if (pop( &s, &data ))
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", data );
    }

    if (pop( &s, &data ))
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", data );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Error:stack is empty." );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
35 -> 25 -> 15 -> Error:stack is empty.
```

Comment: Hello Vlad,
Thank you very much for your detailed information and codes. However, despite my best efforts to adapt your code, I encountered several errors and could not resolve them. Nevertheless, I am grateful for your assistance and appreciate the time you took to help me.

Comment: @Mirza Your own errors have nothing common with the code I provided in my answer. So your question is resolved. To close your question select the best answer. If you have some other problems then ask a new question.